An assertion of Mahler
Let $\rho$ be an integer greater than $1$. In the article "Uber das Verschwinden von Potenzreihen mehrerer Veränderlichen in speziellen Punktfolgen" https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01455711 (page 581)
Mahler asserts that for a polynomial $F$ of $\mathbb C[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_g]$ with degree $f$ in $x_g$, there exists polynomials $F_1$ in $\mathbb C[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{g-1}]$ and $F_2\in \mathbb C[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_g]$ with degree $(\rho-1)f$ in $x_g$ such that the polynomial
$$F_1(x_1,\cdots,x_{g-1})F(x^\rho_1,\cdots,x^{\rho}_g)+F_2(x_1,\cdots,x_g)F(x_1,\cdots,x_g)$$
is a polynomial with degree at most $f-1$ in $x_g$. I did not manage to prove that assertion.
Any help would be welcome to overcome this difficulty. Thanks in advance for any answer.

Please use a high-level tag like "ac.commutative-algebra". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

Let us introduce the notation
$$R:=\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dotsc,x_{g-1}]\qquad\text{and}\qquad K:=\mathbb{C}(x_1,\dotsc,x_{g-1}).$$
Let us regard
$$F:=F(x_1,\dotsc,x_g)\qquad\text{and}\qquad G:=F(x_1^\rho,\dotsc,x_g^\rho)$$
as elements of the polynomial ring $K[x_g]$. Clearly, the $x_g$-degrees of $F$ and $G$ are
$$\deg F=f\qquad\text{and}\qquad\deg G=\rho f.$$
By applying the Euclidean division algorithm to $F$ and $G$, we obtain polynomials $A,B\in K[x_g]$ such that
$$G=AF+B,\qquad\text{where}\quad\deg A=(\rho-1)f,\quad\deg B<f.$$ As $K$ is the quotient field of $R$, we can write
$$A=-F_2/F_1\qquad\text{and}\qquad B=F_3/F_1$$
with suitable $F_1\in R$ and $F_2,F_3\in R[x_g]$.
Then, in the polynomial ring $R[x_g]$, we have the identity
$$F_1 G+F_2 F=F_3.$$
Note that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are nonzero, because $A$ is nonzero. Moreover, the $x_g$-degrees of $F_2$ and $F_3$ are
$$\deg F_2=\deg A=(\rho-1)f\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\deg F_3=\deg B<f,$$
so we have verified Mahler's claim.
